# puesta en produccion symfony mercadopago

Tags: javascript, mercadopago, symfony3

Problema al integrar la plataforma de pago Mercadopago con el SDK de symfony.
En Modo TEST funciona a la perfección con las credenciales de TEST pero en producción no consigo obtener el error y solucionarlo. 
Como puedo obtener el error específico que devuelve la API y mostrarlo para identificar si es un error de tarjeta o de donde viene?

Comment: Estás usando el checkout? o el SDK completo?